# Not in the style and javascript yet is am trying do a html form button only

Tags: html, forms

I tried to make button it does not work it is it's supposed to say submit but that it just has a square.I not doing css yet to style my online video instructor has not talked yet so i need help for to have button
on my website and the say submit i do not was wrong did the same i think?? please help me .

Comment: Did you actually write some html? Show it, then we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you not only want the button to display "submit" but to trigger something when it is pressed, i.e. submit data to the web server. The straightforward way would indeed be to use a form:

```
<form action="[NAME_OF_SERVER_SCRIPT]">
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```